# Matlab Dimensions Swapped in Meshgrid

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, dimensions

In something which made me spent several hours, I have found an inconsistency in how Matlab deals with dimensions. I somebody can explain to me OR indicate me how to report this to Matlab, please enlight me.

For `size`, `ones`,`zeros`,`mean`, `std`, and most every other old and common commands existing inside Matlab, the dimension arrangement is like the classical one and like the intended standard (as per the `size` of every dimension), the first dimension is along the column vector, the second dimension is along the row vector, and the following are the non graphical following indexes.

```
>x(:,:,1)=[1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8];
>x(:,:,2)=[9 10 11 12;13 14 15 16];

>m=mean(x,1)
m(:,:,1) = 3     4     5     6
m(:,:,2) = 11    12    13    14

m=mean(x,2)
m(:,:,1) =
    2.5000
    6.5000
m(:,:,2) =
   10.5000
   14.5000

m=mean(x,3)
m =  5     6     7     8
     9    10    11    12

d=size(m)
d =  2     4     2
```

However, for graphical commands like `stream3`,`streamline` and others relying on the `meshgrid` output format, the dimensions 1 and 2 are **swapped!**: the first dimension is the row vector and the second dimension is the column vector, and the following (third) is the non graphical index.

```
> [x,y]=meshgrid(1:2,1:3)
x =  1     2
     1     2
     1     2
y =  1     1
     2     2
     3     3
```

Then, for `stream3` to operate with classically arranged matrices, we should use `permute(XXX,[2 1 3])` at every 3D argument:

```
xyz=stream3(permute(x,[2 1 3]),permute(y,[2 1 3]),permute(z,[2 1 3])...
    ,permute(u,[2 1 3]),permute(v,[2 1 3]),permute(w,[2 1 3])...
    ,xs,ys,zs);
```

If anybody can explain why this happens, and can indicate to me why this is not a bug, welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Columns are either "j" or "x" in the documentation, rows are either "i" or "y".

Some functions deal with spatial coordinates. The documentation will refer to "x, y, z". These functions will thus take column values before row values as input arguments.

Some functions deal with array indices. The documentation will refer to "i, j" (or sometimes "i1, i2, i3, ..., in", or using specific names instead of "i" before the dimension number). These functions will thus take row values before column values as input arguments.

Yes, this can be confusing. But if you pay attention to the names of the variables in the documentation, you will quickly figure out the right order.

With `meshgrid` in particular, if the "x, y, ..." order of arguments is confusing, use `ndgrid` instead, which takes arguments in array indexing order.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning ngrid. It's been a while since I more than dabbled with Matlab

Comment: Confirmed, `ndgrid` matches [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html): `ndgrid(linspace(0,1,5), linspace(1,-1,8), linspace(.5,0,4))` == `np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1,5), np.linspace(1,-1,8), np.linspace(.5,0,4))`

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Look again, those two are not exactly the same. The output array sizes are different, the first two dimensions are swapped.

Comment: Well, that's what I get for assuming things. It matches [`np.mgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) via `np.mgrid[0:1:5j, 1:-1:8j, .5:0:4j]` - or `np.meshgrid`with `indexing='ij'`.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is not a bug because it is clearly documented as the intended behavior: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html. Specifically:

> `[`[`X`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html#bvblp7l-X),[`Y`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html#bvblp7l-Y),[`Z`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html#bvblp7l-Z)`]= meshgrid(`[`x`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html#bvblp7l-x),[`y`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html#bvblp7l-y),[`z`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html#bvblp7l-z)`)` returns 3-D grid coordinates defined by the vectors `x`, `y`, and `z`. The grid represented by `X`, `Y`, and `Z` has size `length(y)`-by-`length(x)`-by-`length(z)`.

Without speaking to the original authors, the exact motivation may be a bit obscure, but I suspect it has to do with the fact that the y-axis is generally associated with the rows of an image, while x is the columns.